# Бот не получает сообщения из телеграм каналов

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу приложение на nodejs. Для работы с телеграм ботом использую node-telegram-bot-api .

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = 'mytoken';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});
bot.onText(/\/chatid/, (msg) => {
  console.log(msg.chat.id);
});
```

Почему данный код не видит сообщение из телеграм каналов. С группами все отлично и с личными чатами. Что нужно сделать что бы бот увидел сообщения телеграм канала?
Это событие так же не видит сообщения.

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
   console.log(msg.chat.id);
});
```

Бот добавлен в канал как администратор.

Comment: выведи в консоль TelegramBot. он вообще импортнулся?

Comment: await bot.start() не забыл вызывать?

Comment: @letUser говорю же он работает=) с чатами все ок, в том числе и с группами. Проблема именно с КАНАЛАМИ. Что код рабочий - не сомневайтесь. 
Мне интересно как с каналами работать. Когда бот добавлен в канал и ему нужно прослушать его.

Comment: @c_k_rim нет. Бот работает, все супер. Пока бота в канал не добавишь... От каналов он сообщения не видит.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения сообщений именно из канала используйте event channel_post:

```js
#! /usr/local/bin/node

const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

// replace the value below with the Telegram token you receive from @BotFather
const token = 'YOUR-TOKEN-HERE';

// Create a bot that uses 'polling' to fetch new updates
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {
  polling: {
    params: {
      interval: 1,
      autoStart: true,
      timeout: 5,
      offset: -1,
    }
  }
});

bot.on('channel_post', async msg => {
  console.log(msg);
})
```